# Extract JSON from Remote Object

Tags: visualforce, json, remote-objects

There is remote object

```
var case = new Case({Subject:'Test', Status: 'Open'});
```

How to get/extract json {Subject:'Test', Status: 'Open'} from case reference?
Is there some documented approach like case.data()..

Answer (score 1):

`case.toJSON()` works in mobileSDK

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Javascript why not just use JSON.parse() once you retrieve your object?